# Map values of a column with ArrayType based on values from another dataframe in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

What I have:

```
| ids.   |items   |item_id|value|timestamp|
+--------+--------+-------+-----+---------+
|[A,B,C] |1.0     |1      |5    |100      | 
|[A,B,D] |1.0     |2      |6    |90       | 
|[D]     |0.0.    |3      |7    |80       |
|[C]     |0.0.    |4      |8    |80       |
+--------+--------+-------+-----+----------
```

```
| ids    |id_num  |
+--------+--------+
|A       |1       |
|B       |2       |
|C       |3       |
|D       |4       |
+---+----+--------+
```

What I want:

```
| ids    |
+--------+
|[1,2,3] |      
|[1,2,4] |    
|[3]     | 
|[4]     | 
+--------+
```

Is there a way to do this without an explode? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will have to write a udf

Comment: You can avoid a `udf` if you're using spark 2.4+

Comment: @pault how can I avoid a udf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

# Suppose this is the dictionary you want to map
map_dict = {'A':1, 'B':2,'C':3,'D':4}

def array_map(array_col):
    return list(map(map_dict.get, array_col))
"""
If you prefer list comprehension, you can return [map_dict[k] for k in array_col]
"""

array_map_udf = udf(array_map, ArrayType())

df = df.withColumn("mapped_array", array_map_udf(col("ids")))
```

I can't think of a different method, but to get a parallelized dictionary, you can just use the `toJSON` method. It will require further processing on the kind of reference df you have:

```
import json
df_json = df.toJSON().map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

Comment: This would require bringing the second dataframe into memory to create map_dict. Is there a way to avoid that? I want to do this for a very large dataset.

Comment: @justneedsomehelppls I have tried to bring you a distributed dictionary, which requires further processing to get a map as I have mentioned. But I don't have a reproducible sample of any of your `df`'s